# How to store and retrieve Access Token using MSAL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-msal

I am working on ASP.NET MVC application. This app get a access token to gain access the resource in the API. Once it get the access token then I want to store it and use it when I need it to call the API in different controller.

However, I want to store, retrieve and refresh and want to have understanding of `AcquireTokenSilently()`.

We may get the token after user sign-in in Startup.cs and then it can be saved and retrieve to access API. So, it might be checked for expire token and then refresh or acquire token silently to access API resource. So whatever flow makes sense.

I have read several document for MSAL but did not get the clear picture and getting confused by `AcquireTokenSilently()`, `Refresh()`. Please see the below code where I am accessing token but I am not storing it.

```
private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
{
        notification.HandleCodeRedemption();

        var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .Build();
        try
        {

            var apiScope = "api://28178a67-4ae6-43d4-b708-c02785516b1d/asses_as_users api://28178a67-4ae6-43d4-b708-c02785516b1d/AzAdUtility.Get";
            string[] scopes = apiScope.Split(' ');
            var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = "AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync threw an exception";
            notification.HandleResponse();
            notification.Response.Redirect($"/Home/Error?message={message}&debug={ex.Message}");
        }
}
```

**Update**

This link below guided me to implement the token cache in ASP.NET MVC. I do have some issues but I did get the idea of caching token.

Note: The issue is related to the dev environment when the program is stopped from Visual Studio or browser window is closed the cache is seem to be missing.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't store it. MSAL does. It has a [token cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.tokencache?view=azure-dotnet) built in to it. This cache is application specific so that it will need to acquire a token the first time each application is run. You can also use a [Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.publicclientapplicationbuilder.withbroker?view=azure-dotnet) to pull a token from the OS that is associated with the current user logged on.

Comment: Thanks Hack,   for your response.  Actually, I am new to coding. I have visited the page earlier and as I mentioned I am confused to what to use.  So I was looking for examples. Another point is as you mentioned that caching occur automatically, if so I was looking how to retrieve the token to use in controller with AcquireTokenSilent().

Comment: yeah, that's it. Read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview

Comment: The above link is bunch of  links which I need to dig and get confused again. .  I was looking for if someone could give me explanging from the perspective of posted or at least few lines of code.   I some how got to the tutorial with lot of reading and hasle from the link you provided.  Not a direct answer but in respect to your effort I am thanks full to you. It did take me to the point where I got help.  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect

Comment: Yeah, my point was that your existing code would use the MSAL cache. No additional code is needed. If you add the `.WithBroker(true)` then you are also leveraging the OS cache via WAM. Neither case requires you to think about the cache. "It just works"